# I am trying convert a complex SQL query to MongoDB query but i fail when adding condition for joined resultset

Tags: sql, regex, mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

I wrote a SQL query that shows my resultset as i wanted. I wanted to write equivalent for MongoDB. I checked the documentation and other sources to make it achieved but i stuck on adding conditions.

This is my SQL code;

```
--MSSQL AND POSTGRESQL QUERY
SELECT
A.*,
B.SYMPTOM1,
B.SYMPTOM2,
B.SYMPTOM3,
B.SYMPTOM4,
B.SYMPTOM5,
C.RECVDATE,
CASE C.STATE WHEN NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE C.STATE END AS STATE,
CASE C.AGE_YRS WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE C.AGE_YRS END AS AGE_YRS,
(CAST(COALESCE(C.CAGE_YR,0) AS float) + COALESCE(C.CAGE_MO,0.0)) AS VAX_DATE_BIRTHDATE,
C.SEX,
C.RPT_DATE,
C.SYMPTOM_TEXT,
CASE C.DIED WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.DIED END AS DIED,
C.DATEDIED,
CASE C.L_THREAT WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.L_THREAT END AS L_THREAT,
CASE C.ER_VISIT WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.ER_VISIT END AS ER_VISIT,
CASE C.HOSPITAL WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.HOSPITAL END AS HOSPITAL,
CASE C.HOSPDAYS WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE C.HOSPDAYS END AS HOSPDAYS,
CASE C.X_STAY WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.X_STAY END AS X_STAY,
CASE C.DISABLE WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.DISABLE END AS DISABLE,
CASE C.RECOVD WHEN NULL THEN 'U' ELSE C.RECOVD END AS RECOVD,
C.VAX_DATE,
C.ONSET_DATE,
CASE C.NUMDAYS WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE C.NUMDAYS END AS NUMDAYS,
C.LAB_DATA,
CASE C.V_ADMINBY WHEN NULL THEN 'UNK' ELSE C.V_ADMINBY END AS V_ADMINBY,
CASE C.V_FUNDBY WHEN NULL THEN 'UNK' ELSE C.V_FUNDBY END AS V_FUNDBY,
C.OTHER_MEDS,
C.CUR_ILL,
C.HISTORY,
C.PRIOR_VAX,
C.SPLTTYPE,
C.FORM_VERS AS VAERS_FORM_VERSION,
C.TODAYS_DATE,
CASE C.BIRTH_DEFECT WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.BIRTH_DEFECT END AS BIRTH_DEFECT,
CASE C.OFC_VISIT WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.OFC_VISIT END AS OFC_VISIT,
CASE C.ER_ED_VISIT WHEN NULL THEN 'N' ELSE C.ER_ED_VISIT END AS ER_ED_VISIT,
CASE C.ALLERGIES WHEN NULL THEN 'none' ELSE C.ALLERGIES END AS ALLERGIES
    FROM VAERSVAX AS A
        INNER JOIN VAERSSYMPTOMS AS B ON
        A.VAERS_ID = B.VAERS_ID
        INNER JOIN VAERSDATA AS C ON
        A.VAERS_ID = C.VAERS_ID
            WHERE (B.SYMPTOM1 LIKE '%COVID%' OR B.SYMPTOM2 LIKE '%COVID%' OR B.SYMPTOM3 LIKE '%COVID%' OR B.SYMPTOM4 LIKE '%COVID%' OR B.SYMPTOM5 LIKE '%COVID%')
            AND A.VAX_TYPE = 'COVID19'
```

And this is my trying for MongoDB equivalent;

```
    db.VaersVax.aggregate([
   {
       $match: { "VAX_TYPE" : "COVID19" }
   },
   {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "VaersSymptoms",
        localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID", 
        as: "VaersSymptoms" 
      },
   },
   {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "VaersData",
        localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID", 
        as: "VaersData" 
      }
   },
   {
       $project:
       {
           VaersSymptoms:
           {
               $filter:
               {
                   input: "$VaersSymptoms",
                   as: "a",
                   cond: { $in: [ "$$a.SYMTOM1", [db.VaersSymptoms.find({"SYMPTOM1": /COVID/})]]}
               }
           }
       }
   }
]);
```

I am ok with SQL but i am newbie on MongoDB. So i stuck in here. Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: You need to tell what the actual problem is with your code.  Does it error out or not give the correct results.

Comment: I am unable to get correct results actually. I am getting the result like i joined two table on SQL, in here two collections. But i am unable to filter my resultset as like SQL query. I am getting empty resultset.

Comment: I am stuck in filtering my resultset as i wanted. I am joined collections and trying to filter it from there but still not working;
db.VaersVax.aggregate([
   {$match: { "VAX_TYPE" : "COVID19" },},
   {$lookup:{
        from: "VaersSymptoms", localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID",as: "VaersSymptoms" 
      } },
   {$lookup:{
        from: "VaersData", localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID",as: "VaersData" 
      }}]).redact({$cond: { if: {$eq: ["VaersSymptoms.2","COVID-19"]}, then: "$$DESCEND",            else: "$$PRUNE"}});

Comment: Sorry for complex code the comment area is a little area for that code.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve it within my friend's support who understands mongo better than me. To sum up, the last state of mongo script is like this;

```
db.VaersVax.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "VaersSymptoms",
        localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID", 
        as: "VaersSymptoms" 
      }
   },
   {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "VaersData",
        localField: "VAERS_ID",
        foreignField: "VAERS_ID", 
        as: "VaersData" 
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$VaersSymptoms" },
   {
        "$match": {
            "$and":[
                {"VAX_TYPE":"COVID19"},
                {"$or":[
                {"VaersSymptoms.SYMPTOM1": /.*COVID.*/}, 
                {"VaersSymptoms.SYMPTOM2": /.*COVID.*/}, 
                {"VaersSymptoms.SYMPTOM3": /.*COVID.*/},
                {"VaersSymptoms.SYMPTOM4": /.*COVID.*/},
                {"VaersSymptoms.SYMPTOM5": /.*COVID.*/},
            ]}
                ]
        }
    }
]);
```